# "were to" VS "is to"

Tags: conditional-constructions

> 1. The following three major challenges have to be met if a family business **is to** flourish for 100 years and more.
> 2. The following three major challenges have to be met if a family business **were to** flourish for 100 years and more.

Which is the correct way to construct a conditional sentense?

Comment: In your context, #2 isn't valid. Note that *If the plan **were** to work...* would normally be followed by a clause defining some ***consequence*** of the plan working (we're postulating that it *is* going to work in some hypothetical future). Whereas *If the plan **is** to work...* would normally be followed by some ***prerequisite / requirement*** (without which the plan *won't* work).

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT：

You should use the first one, i.e. "The following three major challenges have to be met if a family business **is** to flourish for 100 years and more."

---

Since a family business to flourish for 100 years and more is not impossible, you should be using **Future Real Conditional** explained here: [Future Conditional Forms | ENGLISH PAGE](https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html)

> Future Real Conditional
>
> FORM
>
> [If / When ... simple present ..., ... simple future ...]
>
> [... simple future ... if / when ... simple present ...]
>
> Notice that there is no future in the if- or when-clause.

An example:

> I am going to read if there is nothing on TV.

Comment: Can you rewrite this answer to make it perfectly clear which of OP's sentences is correct, and why?  Even as a native speaker it took me several readings to understand what you are trying to say.  Also you might provide a counter-example to explain what would need to be different to make the other sentence correct.

Comment: You are very kind to offer your ideas, but you do not answer the question.

Comment: I can't really understand this answer, but it seems to be suggesting that OP ***should*** use ***is going to*** instead of plain "Present as Future" ***is to***. It's *possible* to do this, but by no means *necessary*. Imho we'd normally use the simpler form, but offhand I'm not sure if that could ever make any difference to the meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. No, not ***is going to***, because "if + simple present", and ***is going to*** is simple future, not simple present. He should use the first sentence in the question, which is ***is to***. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see your point, though I'm not convinced it's meaningful to talk about a "Simple Future" tense in English (basically, we only have Past and Present; anything else has to be expressed using modal / auxiliary "helper" verbs). But it still seems to me the short answer for OP is that example #2 is invalid because it switches from Present tense ***have** to be met* into Past tense ***were** to flourish. It would be fine if the former were to be changed to ***had** to be met*.